# Get all values from td of a row if checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table.

```html
<table id="tab1">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Select</th>
         <th>Name of the item</th>
         <th>Qty</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="record"></td>
         <td id="name"></td>
         <td id="qty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="record"></td>
         <td id="name"></td>
         <td id="qty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="record"></td>
         <td id="name"></td>
         <td id="qty"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="record"></td>
         <td id="name"></td>
         <td id="qty"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to get all the items in json format from the rows of the table where the checkbox is checked.

What i have tried :-

```
$(".submit-row").click(function () {
  alert("items submitted");
  var s = $('#tab1 tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').find('td')
  //console.log(s)

  var jsonObj = [];
  $("#tab1 tr").slice(1).each(function (index, element) {

    item = {}

    item["name"] = $(this).find('td#name').text();
    item["number"] = $(this).find('td#qty').text();

    jsonObj.push(item);

  });
  console.log(jsonObj)

});
```

I tried using checked property too, but no luck.

```
$("table > tbody > tr").each(function () {
  if ($(".checkBoxClass").is(":checked")) {
    console.log($(this).find('td').eq(1).text() + " " + $(this).find('td').eq(2).text());
  }
});
```

All the elements get selected in both the solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your jQuery code, you're finding ALL elements on the page which have the class `checkBoxClass` and checking is ANY of them are checked...

```
if ($(".checkBoxClass").is(":checked")) {
```

Instead you want to get the one based on the current element within the `.each`...

```
$("table > tbody > tr").each(function () {
  if ($(this).find(".checkBoxClass").is(":checked")) {
    console.log($(this).find('td').eq(1).text() + " " + $(this).find('td').eq(2).text());
  }
});
```

You can also make it a little bit more efficient by not repeating `$(this)`...

```
$("table > tbody > tr").each(function () {
  var $tr = $(this);
  if ($tr.find(".checkBoxClass").is(":checked")) {
    var $td = $tr.find("td");
    console.log($td.eq(1).text() + " " + $td.eq(2).text());
  }
});
```

---

So you're aware, your HTML is also invalid, as you can't have multiple elements with the same `id`... which you have with `<td id="name">` and `<td id="qty">`.  You're better off using classes...

```js
$(function(){
  $(".checkBoxClass").on("click", function() {
    var data = [];
    $("table > tbody > tr").each(function () {
      var $tr = $(this);
      if ($tr.find(".checkBoxClass").is(":checked")) {
        data.push({
          name: $tr.find(".name").text(),
          number: Number($tr.find(".qty").text())
        });
      }
    });
    console.clear();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab1">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Select</th>
         <th>Name of the item</th>
         <th>Qty</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="record"></td>
         <td class="name">One</td>
         <td class="qty">1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="record"></td>
         <td class="name">Two</td>
         <td class="qty">2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="record"></td>
         <td class="name">Three</td>
         <td class="qty">3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="record"></td>
         <td class="name">Four</td>
         <td class="qty">4</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply, can you tell me how can i save this as a json, kinda new to jquery

Comment: [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: BTW, your HTML is invalid, as you cannot have multiple elements with the same `id` (which you have with `<td id="name">` and `<td id="qty">`)... you're better off using classes

Comment: @penta - see my edit for full working example, including the JSON.stringify

Answer (score 2):

You can try using following snippet.

**HTML**

```
<table id="tab1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Name of the item</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="record"></td>
      <td id="name">A</td>
      <td id="qty">B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="record"></td>
      <td id="name">C</td>
      <td id="qty">D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="record"></td>
      <td id="name">E</td>
      <td id="qty">F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="record"></td>
      <td id="name">G</td>
      <td id="qty">H</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table><table id="tab1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Name of the item</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="record"></td>
      <td id="name">I</td>
      <td id="qty">J</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="record"></td>
      <td id="name">K</td>
      <td id="qty">L</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="record"></td>
      <td id="name">M</td>
      <td id="qty">N</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxClass" name="record"></td>
      <td id="name">O</td>
      <td id="qty">P</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="submit-row">Submit</submit>
```

**JS**

```
$(".submit-row").click(function(){
  let chkboxes = $('.checkBoxClass');

  for(let i = 0; i < chkboxes.length; i++) {
    if (chkboxes[i].checked) {
      let parentTr = chkboxes[i].parentNode.parentNode; 

      let name = $(parentTr)[0].children[1].innerHTML;
      let qty = $(parentTr)[0].children[2].innerHTML;

      let obj = {
        'chk': true,
        name,
        qty
      }

      console.log(obj);
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the codepen - https://codepen.io/aditya-bhave/pen/orVGWm

Comment: No need to use codepen when stackoverflow provides [snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Agreed. It was loading slow on my computer. Thats why I used codepen.